# SOAP with MTOM in .Net Core 3.1 - ChillKat?

Tags: soap, mtom, netcoreapp3.1

Is ChillKat the way to go for processing xop messages? My service has to receive a MTOM request and send back a MTOM response.

I’ve been looking into MTOM for .Net Core 3.1. Eventhough MTOM is not supported at this time, ChillKat shows how MTOM responses can be created.

However, I get no sense of how the library can be used with a httpcontex object.

https://www.example-code.com/dotnet-core/mtom_xop_attachment.asp

Anyone with an insight how to use it?